# Using AzCopy in azure virtual machine

Tags: azure, blob, azure-blob-storage

I have an azure virtual machine which has some application specific CSV files(retrieved via ftp from on-premise) that needs to be stored into a blob (and eventually will be read and pushed into a Azure SQL DB via a worker role). Question is around pushing the files from VM to blob. Is it possible to get AzCopy without installing the SDK to have the files copied to the blob? Is there a better solution than this?  Please read the points below for further information

Points to note:
1) Though files could be directly uploaded to a blob rather than getting them into the VM first and copying from there, for security reasons the files will have to be pulled into the VM and this cannot be changed.
2) I also thought about a worker role talking to a VM folder share (via common virtual network) to pull the files and upload to the blob, but this does not appear to be a right solution after reading some blogs - as it requires changes to both VMs (worker role VM and the Iaas VM).
3) Azure File Service is still in preview (?) and hence cannot be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to get AzCopy without installing the SDK to have the
>   files copied to the blob?

Absolutely yes. You can directly download AzCopy binaries without installing SDK using the following links:

**Version 3.1.0**: http://aka.ms/downloadazcopy

**Version 4.1.0**: http://aka.ms/downloadazcopypr

**Source**: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2015/01/13/azcopy-introducing-synchronous-copy-and-customized-content-type.aspx

Comment: Thanks Gaurav. That was quick! BTW, do you see a better solution that this? The ultimate goal is to get the data in the files (stored in the VM) to be updated into the Azure SQL Database. Any direct way to do this instead of doing VM->(via AzCopy)->Blob->(via worker role)->SqlDatabase?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the files are available locally and then they will be pushed into a VM using FTP. Correct? Assuming you're using Azure Virtual Machines (IaaS) and not Cloud Services (PaaS) and there's no need to distribute the file processing job, you could simply keep them in Virtual Machine itself and get them processed as Azure Virtual Machines are stateful VMs. Keeping them in blobs improve the scalability aspect though where multiple VMs can process different files.

Comment: use automation instead, so you don't need to run it on the VM itself :-)  : take a look here https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Copy-and-Item-from-an-c283405d and here https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Copy-Files-from-a-Local-0b8de545 to combine both of them into one single Runbook , that way you don't need to update your SDK's either on the VM ;-)

Comment: @GauravMantri - Yes that's correct. But as the data in the files need to go into the SQL DB, is there a direct way to do this instead of involving a blob and worker role? If you meant to avoid just the blob and read from VM and update the DB, the connectivity between VM and the worker role is not a recommended approach as it requires changes to both VMs as I understand. Thanks again.

Comment: @techmike2kx - Thanks mike for the information. I am currently investigation Runbook and it is interesting when you said "you don't need to run it in the VM"..will explore the links. Appreciate your inputs.